# How to make Gradle show source of dependency conflicts?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I use Gradle `resolutionStrategy` to fail the build if there're conflicting dependency versions:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}
```

In case of a conflict I receive the following message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':module:testCompileClasspath'.
> A conflict was found between the following modules:
  - com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.6.6
  - com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.4.1
```

How to make Gradle display dependency paths for those artifacts?

Now I have to remove `failOnVersionConflict()` from `build.gradle` to be able to run `dependencies` task and than search for occurrences of the conflicting artifacts. Repeating these steps time after time is very annoying as you may guess.

Comment: Relevant Gradle issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3033

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to see a message with it saying :

```
Run with:
    --scan or
    :dependencyInsight --configuration _classStructurekaptKotlin --dependency org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: next time include cli example instead of cut and paste

Comment: I don't see you answering the question at all